# Opening multiple URLs with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

Windows 10 x64 / Python 2.7 / Selenium

I am trying to build a tool to scrape my ticket queue for unassigned tickets, open them and look for keywords, then do other things. But for now, I can't seem to figure out getting the code to open more than the first URL. I keep getting a **StaleElementReferenceException** error; and I do not understand why.

I'm building on top of examples I have found. This may not even be a good way to go about this. I am open to a new direction as well.

The goal for this will be to have something scrape the queue every X and when certain keywords are found offer me a prompt to assign it. It needs to run on its own while I am doing other tasks so it can not interfere with my keystrokes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest

class LoginTest (unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://TICKETS.COMPANY.COM/TEAM/MINE")

    def test_Login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        table = "UNASSIGNED-TICKETS"

        # Select the UNASSIGNED-TICKETS tab
        selectUnassignedTab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_link_text('Unassigned'))
        selectUnassignedTab.click()

        # Grab all of the Ticket URLs
        unlockedTickets = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='unlocked-tickets']/tbody/tr[@role='row']/td[@class='nowrap']/a[@href]"))


        counter = 1
        dictURLs={}
        for ticket in unlockedTickets:
            ticketUrl = ticket.get_attribute('href')
            # Troubleshooting: Make sure URLs are grabbed.
            print ticket.get_attribute('href')

            # Stuff them in a dict
            dictURLs["string{0}".format(counter)]=ticketUrl


            # Open each ticket (NOT WORKING)
            # driver.get(ticketUrl) <--- Causes the Stale Element Error

            if counter == 1:
                # Wait for the User and Pass fields to load. Then assign them.
                emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name('username'))
                passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name('password'))

                # Log in information.
                emailFieldElement.clear()
                emailFieldElement.send_keys("USERNAME-HERE")
                passFieldElement.clear()
                passFieldElement.send_keys("PASSWORD-HERE")
                passFieldElement.submit()

            counter = counter + 1

    def tearDown(self):
        sleep(15)
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to open multiple windows and it worked like a charm

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
import time


def test_logic():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    url = 'https://www.google.co.in'
    driver.get(url)
    # Implement your test logic
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

N = 5   # Number of browsers to spawn
thread_list = list()

# Start test
for i in range(N):
    t = threading.Thread(name='Test {}'.format(i), target=test_logic)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print t.name + ' started!'
    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all thre<ads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print 'Test completed!'
```